# changing between fragments the viewmodel is not working

Tags: android

I'm using viewmodel with injection. In my scnario, I have two fragments. A one is A, and the other is B.
When using A Viewmodel, it's working. But after changing A -> B -> A, The A Viewmodel is not working.
I don't understand why the viewmodel is not working. the only way I solved is  generating a new fragment A. But I want to use DaggerFragment. please let me know why this happens.

*viewmodel injection code*

```
 class AFragment : DaggerFragment(){
    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory : ViewModelProvider.Factory
    private val viewModel by viewModels<HomeViewModel>{viewModelFactory}

   override fun onCreateView (inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        binding = FragmentHomeFirstwalkingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container,false).apply {
            viewmodel = viewModel
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initLayout()
    }

    private fun initLayout(){
      
        binding.title.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.getTrainingDataList("sad")
        }
    }
}
```

binding.title.setOnClickListener is not working after changing fragments.

Comment: So where do you declare your `binding` object? Please include all code related to that.

Comment: Please provide `binding` code too, in the question.

Comment: I updated adding binding code

Comment: What does "the viewmodel is not working" mean?

Comment: the A fragment is shown at first, and If I click  `binding.title.setOnClickListener {
            viewModel.getTrainingDataList("sad")
        }`  it's working. After changing A fragment to B, and then changing B to A, the A fragment viewmodel is not working. this line  `viewModel.getTrainingDataList("sad")`

Comment: I can solve this problem generating a new viewmodel like this `val homeViewModel = HomeViewModel(defaultRepository)` , but is it a good solution?